# MySQL Clone matching rows and amend one field with unique PHP generated value

Tags: mysql, sql, row, clone, unique-key

I'd like to clone all the rows that have YEAR=2020, and assign the GAMECODE field to be the value generated by the php function.

However at the moment that gamecode is only generated once so I am getting a **"Duplicate entry"** error.

```
$number = generateGameCode();   

$sql = "INSERT INTO games(gamecode, year, rounds)
        SELECT '".$number."', year, rounds
        FROM games
        WHERE year = 2020";
```

How do I assign a unique newly generated game code for each matching row?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I have to use my php function to generate the value. I cannot just set GAMECODE to auto_increment number in the db.

Comment: You can't call a php function from within a SQL query. You can either read and update rows one by one in php (which is inefficient), or rebuild your php function as a SQL function or stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  You let the database do that work.  This requires restructuring the table.  But the table should look like:

```
create table games (
    gamecode int auto_increment primary key,
    year int,
    rounds int
);
```

Then, you don't insert the `gamecode` (which I would call `gameid` but you can call it whatever you want).  It is generated automatically.  Your query looks like:

```
insert into games (year, round)
    select year, round
    from games
    where year = 2020;
```

Comment: I am aware of that option, however I can't use auto_increment. I have to use my generateRandomNumber() function as that does a bit more.

Comment: Is there any workaround if I have to use the php generated value, please?